# Mini ATX with 4k @60Hz

Tags: motherboard, hdmi

I'm looking for a Mini ATX (if possible with the latest generation of I7 or even new AMD) with a full 4k @60hz / HDMI 2.0

I need at least one PCIe (that why I don't go to mini-STX)

any recommendation ?
Thank you

(the display will be a 3,840 x 2,160 and the power supply is 50/60 Hz.)

I like full 4K, but only find that so far

Jetway NF594-Q170 Mini-ITX Motherboard (don't know nothing about Jetway)
http://www.jetwaycomputer.com/NF594.html

Fatal1ty Z170 Gaming-ITX/ac
http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Fatal1ty%20Z170%20Gaming-ITXac/

Otherwise I was thinking 
ASRock Z170 Gaming-ITX/AC S1151 M-ITX Intel Motherboard  with

G.SKILL TridentZ Series F4-4000C19D-8GTZ 8 GB DDR4 4000 MHz C 19 1.35 V Memory Kit - Dual Colour

and for the CPU I'm not to sure about which one, I5, i7...

PS, silly question but 1 PCIe 3.0 x16, 1 Half-size Mini-PCIe, can I have something like : DVBSky S952 PCIe card

The use : Plex server, DNS server, Torrent server, and playing DVB-S Sat feed from Kodi and IPTV + some video

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard is better the Z170.
for the CPU: if you must also editing videos and graphics design take the i7, if not take i5

Comment: Thanks I bought the i5 at the end it was supposed to be supported regarding the motherboard spec, but at the end is not so at the end I will buy a new CPU 6th generation